# Rickshaw/d3.js - equally-spaced series

Tags: javascript, d3.js, rickshaw

I have a graph made with rickshaw (line graph).

The graph is working fine but unreadable. The time(x) data for the graph is irregular.

e.g:

```
{"x":1387669802,"y":1256},
{"x":1387669803,"y":1273},
{"x":1387669804,"y":1256},
{"x":1387669805,"y":1248},
{"x":1387669820,"y":1281},
...huge time gap...
{"x":1370122812,"y":1281},
{"x":1370122813,"y":1236},
{"x":1370122852,"y":1252},
{"x":1370122822,"y":1281}
```

there are many gaps between a little series of data. sometimes big gaps, sometimes small gaps. What I try is to set a fix distance between two data points.

Last time i worked with morris.js. There was a option named **parseTime** which does exactly that. treating the data as an equally-spaced series. 
http://www.oesmith.co.uk/morris.js/lines.html

Any idea how to do that with rickshaw/d3?

Regards

Comment: For this, you would need to tell Rickshaw to use an ordinal instead of a time scale, which at first glance doesn't appear to be possible.

Comment: There is an xScale parameter. As I understand that, i can provide my own scale. if i set xScale: d3.scale.ordinal() the graph is still rendering but kinda there are only horizontal data lines in my graph now...

Comment: Just telling it to use an ordinal xScale is not enough, because it is still setting the scale's domain and range using the linear scale methods: giving max and min values for each.  So the ordinal scale treats those as the only possible values and alternates between them, hence the zig-zagging lines across the whole width of your graph.  For what you want, the ordinal scale range would be set with `.rangePoints()` and the scale domain would be set by the sorted list of all possible x values.  I tried setting those directly, but the `.render()` method over-writes the custom values.